How do I request permission from the user to access their microphone?
When running an Avalonia desktop application on macOS, how do I trigger the modal for requesting access to a user's microphone? There seems to be no Info.plist file built into the Visual Studio For Mac project template, and manually adding one with a NSMicrophoneUsageDescription key-value pair doesn't seem to make a difference.
For more context, I'm using the libsoundio-sharp-net library which seems to be the only nuget package that could work for recording audio in an Avalonia desktop application targeting macOS. The issue I'm facing is that when I attempt to read the buffer from the user's microphone, I just get an empty array of zeroes. My theory is that this is because the NSMicrophoneUsageDescription has not been granted, but no modal is automatically triggered for the user to grant this permission. (When I've done this in the past with Xamarin.Mac, I used AVFoundation for microphone recording which would automatically trigger this modal). So I'm trying to manually trigger this modal to see if that solves the issue.
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!
